# Reduce number of columns with priority for certain values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to collapse a data frame with < 100 columns fourfold,
whereby the code would iterate over groups of 4 adjacent columns and collapse them into one.
However, the resulting values based on each set of 4, depend on the priority of the value.

For example, the highest priority is '1', so whenever any of the 4 columns has a value '1' for that row it should be the resulting value. The second priority is 0, if the set has one '0' and three NA's, the result should be '0' (as long as there's no '1's). The lowest priority is NA, only sets consisting of NA completely would remain NA. An example below, with reproducible code underneath.

```
  ID c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8
row1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA
row2 NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA
```

becomes

```
  ID c1 c2
row1  1  1
row2  0 NA
```

```
structure(list(ID = c("row1", "row2"), c1 = c(1, NA), c2 = c(0, 
NA), c3 = c(0, NA), c4 = c(0, 0), c5 = c(1, NA), c6 = c(0, NA
), c7 = c(0, NA), c8 = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("row1", "row2"), c1 = c(1, NA), c2 = c(0, 
                                                             NA), c3 = c(0, NA), c4 = c(0, 0), c5 = c(1, NA), c6 = c(0, NA
                                                             ), c7 = c(0, NA), c8 = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                    -2L))

out <- data.frame(ID = dat$ID)
k <- 2 # first column to start
i <- 1 # first variable name
while(k < ncol(dat)){
  out[[paste0("c", i)]] <- apply(dat[,k:(k+3)], 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)
  out[[paste0("c", i)]] <- ifelse(is.finite(out[[paste0("c", i)]]), out[[paste0("c", i)]], NA)
  k <- k+4
  i <- i+1
}
#> Warning in FUN(newX[, i], ...): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
out
#>     ID c1 c2
#> 1 row1  1  1
#> 2 row2  0 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
f <- function(x) fifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA_real_,1*(sum(x,na.rm = T)>0))

dcast(
  melt(setDT(df),"ID",variable.name = "v")[
    ,f(value), .(ID,r=paste0("c",rep(1:(uniqueN(v)/4), each=uniqueN(v))))],
  ID~r, value.var = "V1",
)
```

Output:

```
     ID c1 c2
1: row1  1  1
2: row2  0 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *split.default* to split dataframe every 4th column, then use *pmax*:

```
x <- df1
x[ is.na(x) ] <- -1
res <- cbind(df1[ "ID" ],
               lapply(split.default(x[, -1], rep(1:2, each = 4)), 
                      function(i) do.call(pmax, i)))

res[ res == -1 ] <- NA
res
#     ID 1  2
# 1 row1 1  1
# 2 row2 0 NA
```

Comment: So this works as long as I split by groups of 4 columns, however only for that.
If I try 'each=10' for example, I get the error,
Error in (function (..., na.rm = FALSE) : no arguments

Comment: @Treebeard Provide representative example data, how many columns do you have and how many columns do you want to collapse into 1?

Comment: Sorry , I tried to make a minimum reproducible example.  I have the ID column + 140 columns. Say I want to collapse each bout of 10 into 1

Comment: @Treebeard try `rep(1:14, each = 10)`

Comment: This works, thanks. Could you perhaps shed light on what the 1:14 means here?

Comment: @Treebeard read about rep function. I am creating 1 to 14 numbers, 1,2,3,...14, then repeating each 10 times, which gives me 14 groups with 10 columns each - totalling to 140 columns.